# How to show a list of maven modules built using Jenkinsfile

Tags: maven, jenkins-pipeline

When I create a maven build in Jenkins and run it I will see all the submodules that were built (with their status).

How to achieve that when using pipeline script Jenkinsfile? Is there a plugin for that?

EDIT: Added image showing what I mean (see the *Module Builds* section on the image)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to run additional step to archive results. Try similar code:

```
node {
    git url: 'https://github.com/joe_user/simple-maven-project-with-tests.git'
    def mvnHome = tool 'M3'
    sh "${mvnHome}/bin/mvn -B -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore verify"
    step([$class: 'ArtifactArchiver', artifacts: '**/target/*.jar', fingerprint: true])
    step([$class: 'JUnitResultArchiver', testResults: '**/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'])
}
```

ArtifactArchiver has short version:

```
archive '**/target/*.jar'
```

Comment: But it gives me only the build artifacts, not the modules that were run (and their status, yellow, red, blue)

Comment: I've updated my question with an image showing which section I miss.

Comment: Seems like it's work of Analysis Collector Plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Analysis+Collector+Plugin Will try to find how to enable it in workflow.